# How to treat commission paid status in fact table - STAR SCHEMA ECOMMERCE

Tags: database, oracle, data-warehouse

I'm completely new to data warehousing and i don't know if i'm doing it right or not.

I'm designing a vendor based E-commerce platform, in which vendors would be adding different products and customers would purchase them, a customer can order from different vendors at once, each order would have the order, customer, product and vendor information along with the commission paid status (commission the vendor would pay for each product sale).

I have converted my OLTP into OLAP using star schema, in star schema i have the following fact and dimension tables.

**Fact Sales Table:**

(In this table i'm maintaining the records of product sales and i have to maintain the record whether the vendor has paid commission against the transaction or not)

1. product_id (fk)
2. customer_id (fk)
3. vender_id (fk)
4. order_id (fk)
5. category_id (fk)
6. time_id (fk)
7. product_salesprice
8. product_quantity
9. commission paid status (since this is not a measure, i can not call it in the fact table, right? but where do i call it then?)

This commission paid table is in my order details table in the OLTP, once the vendor pays the commission against a specific product he sold the status would be true, this is how the system would generate profit.

I have the following dimensions:

1. customer
2. vendor
3. product
4. order
5. time
6. category

Comment: What is your concrete question?

Comment: I need to maintain the record of commission paid status against each transaction, how do i do it? The way i'm doing it is i'm putting it in the fact table but this is logically wrong since i'm only allowed to put measures in the fact table.

Comment: Do i need to create another dimension? Or should i create another fact table, if i should go with the fact table then how to do it? Since only measures can be kept in the fact table.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a Commission Paid Status dimension, but many would consider this overkill, for just one column. However you should indeed avoid putting this kind of textual category into your fact table.

Instead, the standard technique is to collect various small flags and statuses into a dimension, called a 'junk' dimension. It makes the dimensional model easier to work with, to have a dimension for these details.

It is misleadingly named, because these flags are still useful for analysis: it is just that they don't belong in the other dimensions.  You build them by making one row per combination of the various flags/statuses within.

In your case you only have one of these to start with, but as your design progresses you might find more candidates for inclusion in the 'junk' dimension. You might call this dimension 'order details' or 'order status' depending on what you'd include in the dimension, with its surrogate key and at least a commision paid status column.

Comment: Perfectly explained, i have another attribute called vendor delivery confirmation which i can put in the junk dimension, i would just create an order details junk dimension and put these two attributes in that dimension, just wanted to ask that junk dimensions are logically correct, right?

Comment: They certainly are, if you google for Kimball junk dimension you'll find lots of useful information.

Comment: Did some research and came to conclusion that i can keep all my status attributes and yes/no flags in the junk dimension and refer the identity of the junk dimension into the fact table.

Thank you so much.